# C# environment stack overflows when starting dll

Tags: c#, c++, interface

I have a piece of C# program loading a dll function:

```
[DllImport("/Users/frk/Workspaces/MySharedLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "MyCFunction")]

public static extern int MyFunction( [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]MyFormat format,  [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] myString,  [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int myStringLength, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] output,  ref UIntPtr outputLength);
```

and calling it

```
int result = MyFunction(format, inPut, inputLength, outPut, ref outputLength);
```

on the C++ side, I have:

MyCPPFunction that works perfectly when called from a C test executable. That MyCPPFunction contains somewhere deep in its dependencies a global const variable declared and initialized in an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace
{
        constexpr unsigned RandTileSize = 256;

        std::array<unsigned, RandTileSize * RandTileSize> GenerateSamples()
        {
            std::array<unsigned, RandTileSize * RandTileSize> samples;

            std::mt19937 rd(0);
            std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> distribution(0, 255);

            for (unsigned i = 0; i < RandTileSize * RandTileSize; ++i)
            {
                samples[i] = distribution(rd);
            }

            return samples;
        };

        const auto samples = GenerateSamples();<-- Option#1 this causes a stack overflow when loading the dll in C# environment

        unsigned Sample(unsigned index)
        {
               static const auto samples = GenerateSamples();<-- Option#2 this works and dll loads correctly
               return samples[index];
        }
}
```

I am confused here since afaik, the option 1 should allocate memory in the code part of the dll, which the C# environment should deal with right ?

How can we have option #1 not to cause memory allocation problems while loading the dll ?

Comment: Where's your code for MyCFunction?

Comment: Bottom line is you need to run it in a C/C++ debugger. You can do this in visual studio, just make sure you have "Native code" debugging turned on.

Comment: Thank you for your question, MyCFunction is defined in the dll API. So its signature is not really relevant. It could have no parameters and return void.

Comment: And debugging shows the stackoverflow exception triggered at "option 1" line.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of a static variable in a function within a DLL is from the first time the statement is encountered, to the time the DLL unloads.

The lifetime of a class or file scoped variable is from the time the DLL loads until the time the DLL unloads.

The consequence of this is that in the failing case, your initialisation code is running **while the DLL is in the process of loading**.

It is not generally a good idea to run nontrivial code in class constructors, as there are limits to what can safely be done inside the loader lock.

In particular if you perform any action which requires dynamically loading another DLL (such as `LoadLibrary` or calling a delay-load linked function) this is likely to cause difficult-to-diagnose issues.

Without diagnosing exactly what has gone wrong in your case the answer is simple: Use option2 or option 3.

Option 3:

```
void MyDLLInitialize(){
    // Initialize the dll here
}

void MyDLLUninitialize(){
   // Uninitialize the dll here
}
```

Then call these functions from C# before you use any other DLL function, and after you have finished with it, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a try and get back to you to let you know if option 3 was successful.

Comment: :-) option 2 is fine. The point really is you can't do anything too complicated in the class or static constructor or destructor because that runs when the DLL is loaded. That's why windows is full of functions like "CoInitializeEx"